# How to put button on same row as django-bootstrap3 pagination

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am using django-tables2 and django-bootstrap3 to render a table w/ pagination.  I'd like to add a button on the same row as the pagination but my Submit button is showing below the pagination. How should I make the button align to the bottom right of the table along the same row as the pagination links?

Here is my table template:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form method='POST' action='{% url "playlists:add_track" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
        {% render_table table "django_tables2/bootstrap3.html" %}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is the custom bootstrap3.html from the tables2 app:

```
{% load querystring from django_tables2 %}
{% load trans blocktrans from i18n %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% if table.page %}
    <div class="table-responsive">
{% endif %}

{% block table %}
    <table{% if table.attrs %} {{ table.attrs.as_html }}{% endif %}>
        {% block table.thead %}
            <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for column in table.columns %}
                    {% if column.orderable %}
                        <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}><a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_order_by_field=column.order_by_alias.next %}">{{ column.header }}</a></th>
                    {% else %}
                        <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}>{{ column.header }}</th>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            </thead>
        {% endblock table.thead %}
        {% block table.tbody %}
            <tbody>
            {% for row in table.page.object_list|default:table.rows %} {# support pagination #}
                {% block table.tbody.row %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle "odd" "even" %}">
                        {% for column, cell in row.items %}
                            <td {{ column.attrs.td.as_html }}>{{ cell }}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endblock table.tbody.row %}
            {% empty %}
                {% if table.empty_text %}
                    {% block table.tbody.empty_text %}
                        <tr><td colspan="{{ table.columns|length }}">{{ table.empty_text }}</td></tr>
                    {% endblock table.tbody.empty_text %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        {% endblock table.tbody %}
        {% block table.tfoot %}
            <tfoot></tfoot>
        {% endblock table.tfoot %}
    </table>
{% endblock table %}

{% if table.page %}
    {% block pagination %}
        {% bootstrap_pagination table.page url=request.get_full_path %}
        {#{ table.page|pagination }#}
    {% endblock pagination %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Here is the rendered output where the button is showing below the pagination instead of on the same row:
[image]

Comment: what bootstrap theme are you using?

Comment: This simple slate theme https://bootswatch.com/slate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the table and the button in two adjacent columns:

```
<div class="row">
  <form method='POST' action='{% url "playlists:add_track" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      {% render_table table "django_tables2/bootstrap3.html" %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

UPD.

Table template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form method='POST' action='{% url "playlists:add_track" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
      {% render_table table "django_tables2/bootstrap3.html" %}
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

bootstrap3.html:

```
{% load querystring from django_tables2 %}
{% load trans blocktrans from i18n %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% if table.page %}
    <div class="table-responsive">
{% endif %}

{% block table %}
    <table{% if table.attrs %} {{ table.attrs.as_html }}{% endif %}>
        {% block table.thead %}
            <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for column in table.columns %}
                    {% if column.orderable %}
                        <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}><a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_order_by_field=column.order_by_alias.next %}">{{ column.header }}</a></th>
                    {% else %}
                        <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}>{{ column.header }}</th>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            </thead>
        {% endblock table.thead %}
        {% block table.tbody %}
            <tbody>
            {% for row in table.page.object_list|default:table.rows %} {# support pagination #}
                {% block table.tbody.row %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle "odd" "even" %}">
                        {% for column, cell in row.items %}
                            <td {{ column.attrs.td.as_html }}>{{ cell }}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endblock table.tbody.row %}
            {% empty %}
                {% if table.empty_text %}
                    {% block table.tbody.empty_text %}
                        <tr><td colspan="{{ table.columns|length }}">{{ table.empty_text }}</td></tr>
                    {% endblock table.tbody.empty_text %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        {% endblock table.tbody %}
        {% block table.tfoot %}
            <tfoot></tfoot>
        {% endblock table.tfoot %}
    </table>
{% endblock table %}

{% if table.page %}
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {% block pagination %}
                {% bootstrap_pagination table.page url=request.get_full_path %}
                {#{ table.page|pagination }#}
            {% endblock pagination %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
{% endif %}

            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>

{% if table.page %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Although it made the button go on the same row as the table so i closed the table row and started a new row for pagination and button w/ your suggestion <div class="col-sm-10"> and <div class="col-sm-2">

Comment: @bayman I think I understand. I updated my answer. Have you done something like this?

Comment: Yes works and is pretty similar to what I initially did. I initially didn't put the button inside the bootstrap3.html and left it in the table template and had to move some </div> tags around just to make sure I had tags properly closed.